# MVVM/WPF UI not update when executing method second time

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, binding

I'm having troubles with my UI not updating when my properties change, even though I have INotifyPropertyChange applied. When i run the code the first time, it shows up correct and the UI is updated. While debbuging I can see the new values being set to the strings of the viewmodel and that the OnPropertChange event is fired, it just don't happen anything in the UI. The code below will be in order of events. As extra information, I use the same code to update the viewmodel both in the first and second time.

```
    public partial class Transaktioner : Window
    {
        ViewModelCommon.ViewModel view = new ViewModelCommon.ViewModel();
        private static List<ViewModelCommon.Items2> getAccountingRowsListEdited = new List<ViewModelCommon.Items2>();
        {
            DataContext = view;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async Task GetAccountinTransactionsAsync()
        {
           await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                getAccountingRowsList = client.GetAccountingTransactions(ftglist[index], 0, ref status).ToList();

                foreach (var v in getAccountingRowsList)
                {
                        getAccountingRowsListEdited.Add(new ViewModelCommon.Items2
                        {
                            itemName2 = v.ver.ToString(),
                            value2 = v.text,
                            vertyp = v.vtyp,
                            s2 = v.kto.ToString(),
                            s3 = v.trdat.ToString()
                        });
                }
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await SearchAndDisplayResult();
                });
            });
        }

        private async Task SearchAndDisplayResult(int exclusion = 0)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
             {
                var verfikationer = getAccountingRowsListEdited.Where(u => u.vertyp != exclusion).Count(u => u.s2.ToString().Equals("0"));

                view.VerifikationerTotal = verfikationer.ToString();

             });
        }
```

The ViewModel:

```
class ViewModelCommon
    {
        public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
            {
                if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
                {
                    field = newValue;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            protected void Test(string sb)
            {
                Transaktioner tr = new Transaktioner("");
                tr.ExcludeStringChanged(sb);
            }
        }

public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            private string _verifikationerTotal;
            public string VerifikationerTotal
            {
                get { return _verifikationerTotal; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _verifikationerTotal)
                    {
                        _verifikationerTotal = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("VerifikationerTotal");
                    }
                }
            }

            private string _ExcludeString;
            public string ExcludeString
            {
                get { return _ExcludeString; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _ExcludeString)
                    {
                        _ExcludeString = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("ExcludeString");
                        Test(ExcludeString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The WPF:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxVerifikationerTotal" Text="{Binding VerifikationerTotal}" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="583,182,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99"/>

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="837,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ExcludeString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286"/>
```

The code above works as expected.

In the UI there is an option to introduce the optional attribute to exclude values. Those are bound to the "ExludeString" this also works and fires the event passing it again to the SearchAndDisplayResult(int exclusion = 0) with the replaces value of the int being passed. While debugging I can see that the event can successfully find a new value and passing it to the ViewModel, but it doesn't update the UI.

Are there any thoughts on why the UI is not updated? Thank you in advance!

**The code has been shortend to show the vitals**

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it will be difficult if not impossible to answer the question. One common cause of this kind of problem is that the view model used in the binding is not the same instance of the view model being updated. The code you posted doesn't _appear_ to have that problem, but since it's not a [mcve], there's no way to know for sure. It is odd that you have the `SetProperty()` method in your base view model class, but don't seem to use it. Again, that doesn't seem to be something that would cause your issue, but there's not enough information.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for taking the time to leave a comment on my question. I just now realized I had taken to much away for it to be replicated. I did find a solution to my problem. It had to do with the `ViewModelCommon.ViewModel view = new ViewModelCommon.ViewModel();` not being a private static. I read this in another question where they suggested that since I'm working with async tasks, it might initate a new instance, therefor not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this case was the

```
ViewModelCommon.ViewModel view = new ViewModelCommon.ViewModel();
```

not being set to a private static while working with Tasks.

Comment: Have you solved this? Im fighting with the same issue. My MVVM implemetation works like yours. First time everything is working well, second call, the NotifyPropertyChanged does nothing. It is called from async methods (but the tasks are running and values are changed)